# Display package.mask info gentoo

Tags: gentoo

Is there a tool available in gentoo to simply output *why* a package has been hard masked? Scrolling through the `/usr/portage/profiles` tree and reading every package.mask file applicable for your profile is a bit time consuming.

Especially, because the sorting in the files is by date in the comment, and not alphabetical on package category/name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the question was asked 27 days ago, maybe someone is still interested in an answer:

*equery* (included in app-portage/gentoolkit) can be used to get the reason why a package (PKG) was masked:

```
equery list --portage-tree --mask-reason PKG
```

For more information on the available options and how to read the output just have a look at the man page of equery.

Comment: I was still very interested in the question and feel honored you even considered creating an account to answer this one. :D